# SendGrid renders nothing when the template has "each" in "greaterThan"

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I have a SendGrid's dynamic template with "each" in "greaterThan" like this:

```
{{#greaterThan (length users) 0}}
    <p>not empty</p>
    {{#each users}}
        <p>{{this.name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
{{/greaterThan}}
```

Expected behavior is that I get:

```
<p>not empty</p>
<p>name1</p>
<p>name2</p>
```

but I get:

```
<p>not empty</p>
```

Why is the "each" block dropped?